# Testing images on a tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm Trying to test a tensorflow model with 10 images as batch size and as output get a segmentation of an specific region. Here is the code I'm using to load the model

```
def run(model_path, image_path,graph_path ,output_path):
with tf.Session() as sess:
  model_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(graph_path, clear_devices=True)
  model_saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(LOGDIR))
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  graph = tf.get_default_graph()
  x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[10, 400, 600, 3])
  output = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prediction:0")
  print("Model restored.")
  print('Initialized')
  temp=[]
  import glob
  from scipy import misc
  for file in os.listdir(image_path):
    if file.endswith(".jpg"):
      img = misc.imread(image_path + file)
      img = img.astype('Float32')
      img = np.resize(img,(400,600,3))
      temp.append(img)
  prediction = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x:temp})
  cv2.imwrite(output_path, prediction * 255)
```

But I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [10,400,600,3]
     [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[10,400,600,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: prediction/_265 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_28_prediction", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Does anybody knows were the bug is or if there is another way of testing a model.

Comment: I think you are redefining x here. Feed it by name instead so remove the x=placeholder() line and use something like {'x:0': temp} as a feed dict and let me know what happens.

Comment: @AlWld Thanks that fixed everything !

Comment: Happy to heard, added it as an answer if you can mark it as solved that would be great, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are redefining x here. Feed it by name instead so remove the x=placeholder() line and use {'x:0': temp} as a feed dict.