# Feed data in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, k-means

I am trying to use Kmean with my data But I am having problems feeding data to the graph. My code is here with data sample [GIT](https://gist.github.com/evalsocket/2576f4eb6701df56a8ac96e2747a47c0)

I am Getting error :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
```

Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just FYI, there is an [Estimator for KMeans in TensorFlow contrib](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/KMeansClustering).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bad design to be honest. The placeholder should be defined inside the KMean function. Then you should feed it using its name, so something like

```
feed_dict = {'Placeholder:0': data}
```

[This should be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44146179/4292465)

And then all should be good.